# JUNG2: How can I display multiple edge-label per edge?

Tags: jung

I'm trying to display a network-topology. 
Everything works fine, except I can't figure out how to display two or three labels per edge, one at either end of the edge and (optionally) one in the middle. I've tried a few things, but I haven't found anything that does not involve ugly hacks...

[Here's what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrKhK.png) (with the labels GIMP-ed in)

Is this even possible?

Thanks

rakudave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [JUNG2 API docs](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html) in the package **edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers**. Most work gets done by the **DefaultEdgeLabelRenderer** defined in this package, but you'll have to create your own custom edge label renderer.

The documentation isn't very comprehensive, so you'll need to go through the [sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jung/files/jung/jung-2.0.1/jung2-2_0_1-sources.zip/download) and find the DefaultEdgeLabelRenderer class, and create your own class based on this one that does what you want. You can then set this class as your EdgeLabelRenderer by a call to:

`vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelRenderer(yourEdgeLabelRendererHere);`